# Adding text on glyphicon

Tags: css, html, styling, glyphicons

I want the text to be centered on a glyphicon. I tried few css tags but in vain.Following is my html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span>
            <span>2</span>
        </td>
        <td>John Oliver</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your css please

Comment: What do mean `on glyphicon`? the `2`?

Comment: what is the expected output.. can you show as image representation?

Comment: Added a picture of the expected output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for last Answer. I think this is what you want. have look to demo.

Demo    http://jsfiddle.net/yhq3npxs/

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart icon-size"></i>
   <span class="badge shoppingBadge shoppingBadge-custom">5</span>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-size {
font-size:60px;
 }

 .shoppingBadge-custom{
background: red;
position:absolute;
left:47px;
top:18px;
font-size:14px;
z-index: 3;
 }
```

Comment: This is not what I want Rajan. I have attached a picture

Comment: There is no need to wrap the component in a container or the badge will change its position when resizing the screen, here is an improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/4m61sd3g/

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/379/)**

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;      
}

.glyphicon + span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px; 
    top:5px; /* adjust the top & left values according to your need */      
}
```

hope this is what you want !!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what i want. i have attached an image of how I want it